# rsync back running via cron

Tags: sudo, cron, rsync

I'd like to run the following backup command as recurrent job where User is my username and `/mnt/Rsync_Dell` is a folder I created on OMV5 with static IP:

```
sudo rsync -apEo /home/User/ /mnt/Rsync_Dell/Prova/
```

If I run this command on the terminal, it runs successfully, on the crontab file it fails.

What I do is the following:

1. `crontab -e`
2. Insert `%% * * * * sudo rsync -avzpEo /home/User/Desktop /mnt/Rsync_Dell/prova/`

   where `%%` is any minute in the future just to test it out.

I run on locale other `rsync` commands, and they work. It just seems that the combination crontab on Samba shares fails.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using `sudo` in the crontab instead of just adding the `rsync` command to root's crontab?

Comment: Short answer: I'm noob

Comment: I think that by inserting it in the crontab -e -u root I managed to do that, thank you!

Comment: Are you required to enter a password when using `sudo` on the command line ordinarily?

Comment: Yes I am requires otherwise it fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't give `sudo` a password when using it from your own crontab, and since the purpose of using `sudo` in the first place is to gain root privileges, running your `rsync` command from *root's* crontab rather than from your own seems like a better option.

You may edit the root user's crontab using

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Within it, you would add the same schedule that you show in your question, but without the `sudo` command.